# Odoo 12 Mail notification

Tags: python, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

In Odoo 12 I am trying to get a mail 90 days prior (before) to expiry of subscription and automatically I have created a email template and function for this but iam not receiving any mails

In py file: 
            license_renewal_date = fields.Date("Renewal Date",track_visibility='onchange')

```
    def exp_date1(self):
    before_90_days = datetime.datetime.now().date()- datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
    exp_90days = self.env['(crm.lead.extended)'].search([('(license_renewal_date)','=',before_90_days)])
    template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
    template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```

Comment: Why `exp_90days ` declaration is at fields level?

Comment: def exp_date1(self):
        exp_90days = self.env['(crm.lead.extended)'].search([('(license_renewal_date)','=',before_90_days)])
        template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.crm_lead_mail_template')
        template.send_mail(rec.id, force_send=True)

Comment: If the line is inside a function declaration the name `self` should be defined, Update your question instead of adding the code in comments.

Comment: u want them to be inside the function ? that is it what i want to know is how to minus 90 days from this field -     license_renewal_date = fields.Date("Renewal Date",track_visibility='onchange')

Comment: check now , there is no error but iam not receiving any mails bro even when its meets the criteria

Comment: Check outgoing email server and template configuration. Note that `rec` is undefined,

Comment: sorry for troubling you so much bro , i have checked and changed the both still no mail is coming , i think before_90_days is wrong

Comment: It should return `datetime.date(2020, 3, 11)`, you try to send an email without taking into consideration `before_90_days ` value.

Comment: yup thats what iam trying to do now , idk how check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284033/odoo-12-cant-start-custom-module-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for