# Odoo 12 can't start Custom Module - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, datetime, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

iam new to odoo what iam trying to do is , i want to minus datetime.timedelta(days = 90) that is 90 days from the license_renewal_date = (2021,6,6) how to do it , but when i try iam getting this below error

```
before_90_days = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
datetime.date(2020, 3, 11)

license_renewal_date = (2021,6,6)

exp_90_days = license_renewal_date - datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

in Odoo py file:

```
license_renewal_date = fields.Date("Renewal Date",track_visibility='onchange')

def exp_date1(self):
    before_90_days = datetime.datetime.now().date()- datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
    exp_90days = self.env['(crm.lead.extended)'].search([('(license_renewal_date)','=',before_90_days)])
    template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
    template.send_mail(rec.id, force_send=True)
```

Update :
   i have update still getting the same error some one help me with his

```
@ api.multi
def exp_date1 (self):

    testDateOnly = license_renewal_date.date;

    before_90_days = testDateOnly - datetime.timedelta (days = 90)

    # before_90_days = datetime.datetime.now (). date () - datetime.timedelta (days = 90)

    exp_90days = self.env ['(crm.lead.extended)']. search ([('(license_renewal_date)', '=', before_90_days)])

    template = self.env.ref ('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')

    template.send_mail (self.id, force_send = True)
```

Comment: using only  `... =  (2021,6,6)` you can't create `datetime` object. You have to do `... = datetime.datetime(2021,6,6)`

Comment: @api.multi
    def exp_date1(self):
        before_90_days = datetime.datetime.now().date()- datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
        exp_90days = self.env['(crm.lead.extended)'].search([('(license_renewal_date)','=',before_90_days)])
        template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
        template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)

Comment: thats a field not a domain

Comment: i want this step to work - exp_90_days = license_renewal_date - datetime.timedelta(days=90)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create object `datetime` using only tuple `(2021,6,6)`

```
 license_renewal_date = (2021,6,6)
```

You have to use object `datetime` for this

```
 license_renewal_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 6).date()
```

And this is all your problem.

Now it works without error:

```
import datetime

before_90_days = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)

print(before_90_days)

license_renewal_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 6).date()

exp_90_days = license_renewal_date - datetime.timedelta(days=90)

print(exp_90_days)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i want pass this field while subtracting license_renewal_date = fields.Date("Renewal Date",track_visibility='onchange')

Comment: get value from `fields.Date()` and use with `datetime.datetime()`

Comment: like this ?
    @api.multi
    def exp_date1(self):
        testDateOnly = license_renewal_date.date;
        before_90_days = testDateOnly - datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
        #before_90_days = datetime.datetime.now().date()- datetime.timedelta(days = 90)
        exp_90days = self.env['(crm.lead.extended)'].search([('(license_renewal_date)','=',before_90_days)])
        template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
        template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)

Comment: I don't know what you get with  `testDateOnly = license_renewal_date.date` but I would rather expect `testDateOnly = datetime.datetime(*license_renewal_date.date)`

Comment: I don't know - I have never used `odoo`